# Android - Erro ao buildar App no debug do celular

Tags: java, android

Estou com um problema ao fazer o Debug e gerar uma Apk assinada, quando vou abrir a aplicação é gerado um erro, não estou conseguindo descorbri a solução para este erro, no simulador do Android funciona perfeitamente, mas quando vou debugar pelo celular ele gera um erro ao abrir a aplicação.

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.meuapp, PID: 6687
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.meuapp.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Didn't find class "com.meuapp.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.meuapp-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2880)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1437)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.meuapp.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", 
zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.meuapp-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.meuapp-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2877)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(ActivityThread.java) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1437) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.meuapp.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService
  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
```

Alguém pode me ajudar com este problema?

Comment: Verificou se a classe "MyFirebaseInstanceIDService" realmente existe neste pacote "com.meuapp"? Lembrando que estar na pasta, não significa estar no pacote.

Comment: Realmente não existia no pacote, estou tentando incluir esse pacote em minha aplicação, existe alguma forma de se fazer isto?

Comment: Vai na classe MyFirebaseInstanceIDService, e troca o package dela, deixando somente como com.meuapp